# Replace all \ but not \\

Tags: java, replace

I have tried

```
param = param.replace("\\", "");
```

which changes

```
a\a\\a ---> aaa
```

but i want

```
a\a\\a ---> aa\\a
```

How can i do this? I have tried regex and it has failed me.

```
param = param.replaceAll("(?>!\\)\\", "");
```

Comment: ``\`` is a special regular expression character. You must escape it.

Comment: yes the \\ in the regex is meant to get  a single \

Comment: No, the ``\\`` is currently just the escape sequence for Java's `String` literals.

Comment: And why? Why do you have backslashes in your data in the first place?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by fixing the regex.                            param = param.replaceAll("(?<![\\\\])\\\\(?![\\\\])", "") works to remove single "\", so a\a\\a becomes aa\\a